# Can't access deep children in mount mode with jest in my test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

#### Version

"jest-cli": "^22.4.2",

"babel-jest": "^22.4.1",

"react": "^16.3.2",

#### Summary

I have a component: `<ComponentListRenderer />`.

This component have a children component: `<div />` with button role and which having an `onClick` function.

When `onCick` function is triggered it affect another children component of `<ComponentListRenderer />`, this component is `<Collapse />` and after `onClick` function is triggered it `isOpen` props will pass from `false` to `true`.

This function is called at line `61` of `ComponentsListRenderer` [file](https://paste.gnome.org/pmfnv9la6)

The encountered issue is that i can't test this function in my [test file](https://paste.gnome.org/pwkcoqtot) of `<ComponentListRenderer />`

#### current *bug* behavior

I can't access to `<div />` with it `onClick` function neither to `<Collapse />` component (neither any other child of `<ComponentsListRenderer />`).

#### What actually happens

The log only show my `<ComponentsListRendererUnstyled />` so I can't test my function and check if it properly pass the `<Collapse />` props `isOpen` from `false` to `true`. I test my component using `mount` mode (cause `shallow` mode will not return a deep rendering)

For now i wrote my test (unworking test) like [this](https://paste.gnome.org/pwkcoqtot).

Below is the current log in my terminal after run jest cmd:

```
console.log src/rsg-components/ComponentsList/tests/ComponentsListRenderer.test.js:57
<BootstrapProvider theme={{...}} injectGlobal={false} utils={{...}}>
  <ThemeProvider theme={{...}}>
    <UtilityProvider utils={{...}} theme={{...}}>
      <div className="UtilityProvider-bsdXya eQdoDP">
        <Styled(ComponentsListRendererUnstyled) items={{...}} theme={{...}} useIsolatedLinks={false}>
          <ComponentsListRendererUnstyled className="sc-bdVaJa kOskEB" items={{...}} theme={{...}} useIsolatedLinks={false} />
        </Styled(ComponentsListRendererUnstyled)>
      </div>
    </UtilityProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
</BootstrapProvider>
```

#### What is the expected *correct* behavior?

To test my component `onClick` behaviour i need to be able to access to child component of `<ComponentsListRenderer />`. For me the `console.log()` in my test should return something like below:

```
<BootstrapProvider theme={{...}} injectGlobal={false} utils={{...}}>
  <ThemeProvider theme={{...}}>
    <UtilityProvider utils={{...}} theme={{...}}>
      <div className="UtilityProvider-bsdXya eQdoDP">
        <Styled(ComponentsListRendererUnstyled) items={{...}} theme={{...}} useIsolatedLinks={false}>
          <ComponentsListRendererUnstyled className="sc-bdVaJa kOskEB" items={{...}} theme={{...}} useIsolatedLinks={false}>
            <Ul>
              <Li>
                <div onClick={() => this.onClick()}>
                  <Link>name</Link>
                </div>
                <Collapse isOpen={false}>
                  content
                </Collapse>
           </Li>
         </Ul>
        </Styled(ComponentsListRendererUnstyled)>
      </div>
    </UtilityProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
</BootstrapProvider>
```

Is someone know how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

My bad, I didn't use a correct props `items`.

Using the props below make my child component appear when log:

`items: [
        {
          name: 'First component',
          href: '/#first-component',
          filepath: 'first-component.md',
          heading: false,
          level: 0,
          content: false,
          collapse: true,
          slug: 'introduction',
          components: [],
          sections: [],
        },
      ],`